# Render html from helper in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in a helper, here is the code:

```
    def top_menu_output(parent = Category.where(parent_id: nil))
    parent.each do |p|
      content_tag(:li) do
        parent_id = p.id
        if Category.where(parent_id: parent_id).exists?
          link_to(p.title, p.page_name, class: "parent")
          content_tag(:ul, class: "unstyled") do
            subparent = Category.where(parent_id: parent_id)
            content_tag(:li) do
              top_menu_output(subparent)
            end
          end
        elsif
          link_to(p.title, p.page_name)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

and I call the method in a view like this

```
 <%top_menu_output%>
```

but it renders nothing. What do I do to render all the links and li's? Thank you for your answers.

P.S. If I put the code right in the view it works just fine, but the view is obviously not the right place for the method.

P.P.S. If I call the method like this <%=top_menu_output%> it renders all the stuff from my db CATEGORY ID: 1, PARENT_ID: NIL, PAGE_NAME: "", KEYWORDS: "", DESCRIPTION: "", SEO_TEXT_LEFT: "", SEO_TEXT_RIGHT: "", CREATED_AT: "2014-04-19 22:08:55", UPDATED_AT: "2014-04-19 22:08:55"...

Comment: you forgot the `=`, try this: `<%= top_menu_output %>`

Comment: no, unfortunately it is not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Frederick, changing `each` to `collect` is almost what I want. But it is also necessary to use `concat` and `+` so the properly working method is:

```
def top_menu_output(parent = Category.where(parent_id: nil))
    parent.collect do |p|
      content_tag(:li) do
        parent_id = p.id
        if Category.where(parent_id: parent_id).exists?
          link_to(p.title, p.page_name, class: "parent") +
          content_tag(:ul, class: "unstyled js-menu") do
            subparent = Category.where(parent_id: parent_id)
            top_menu_output(subparent)
          end
        elsif
          concat link_to(p.title, p.page_name)
        end
      end
    end.join.html_safe
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `each` is the collection that is iterated over, so you are generating a whole bunch of html but then returning something else

You could change that to

```
parent.collect do |p|
  content_tag(:li) do
    ...
  end
end.join
```

This would collect the html generated by each iteration through the block, concatenate them all and return that. As pointed out in the comments, you also need to use <%= or you'll never see any output